# AlwaysON SQL Server 2014 Application exception: Failed to update database because database is readonly

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, alwayson

We have two nodes availability group. The two nodes being `SQL cluster1- node1` and `SQL cluster 2- node2` and a Availability group listener. The Java application is connecting to this listener and all is working fine initially i.e application is able to perform both read/writes on the database, untill we do a failover.

The connector string is `driverURL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[Listerner DNS Name]:[Port]/[Database]`

Say initially the node1 was primary and node2 was the secondary.
After failover, node1 becomes secondary and node2 becomes primary. Now the application is still able to connect to the database but only able to perform reads on the database. The application throws exceptions (which is mentioned in the title) if we try to do inserts on that DB.

Basically what I need is for the application to be able to perform read/writes all the time irrespective of which node is the primary. Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

There should be no reason why you get a read-only database when the connection string is pointing to the listener. That's the point of the avail grp listener - to direct flow to the read/write (primary) database. Ping the DNS name and check that it resolves to the listener (before and after an AG failover). Unfortunatelyy I don't use Java so can't help you any further. Cheers, Mark.